# Ajax not working with CGI on an Apache webserver in Ubuntu

Tags: jquery, ajax, apache

Hello I am trying to develop a simple webpage using CGI on the server side. My current goal is to submit a form without reloading the page via Ajax.

The CGI in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

print("Content-Type: text/html \n\n")

f = open("ajax_input.html", "r")
print(f.read())
```

The Current Webpage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>



        <script>
                $('form.ajax').on('submit', function(){
                        alert("Success")
                        return false;


                });
        </script>

        <body>
                <form method="post" class="ajax">
                        <input type="submit" value="Submission">
                </form>
                <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is `changeTex()`?

Comment: Why are you using both `onsubmit` and `$('form.ajax').on('submit'`? They'll both work, but it seems redundant.

Comment: Sorry! Forgot to remove that. Let me edit that now

Comment: Where is the AJAX code? Also, you need to load jQuery before the script that uses it.

Comment: Why are you using obsolete python 2.x?

Comment: I believe that the ajax code is the $(form.ajax). I'm very new to it so if that is incorrect, please let me know. Also I will try loading in jquery right away

Comment: My machine has had issues running python3 in the past where code would work on a different machine, so I've held back with python2 to avoid any issues like that.

Comment: No, there's no AJAX code there. It just prevents the normal form submission, it doesn't replace it with AJAX.

Comment: See the functions `$.ajax`, `$.post`, and `$.get` for jQuery AJAX operations.

Comment: Oh really!? That's not AJAX. So that means that what that is doing specifically is just preventing the form submission? Unfortunately the form still submits even with that there, is there something that I am missing to prevent the form from submitting?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: Oh yes I am, uncaught reference error, $ is not defined.

Comment: That's because you're trying to use `$()` before you load jQuery, so none of that code works.

Comment: Ohhhhh! And I load in the jquery when I do that script line. Let me go change that now.

Comment: I just changed it and it no longer gives me the error, but the page still reloads

Comment: Do you get the alert?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not

Comment: The console isn't giving me any more output, either.

Comment: You need to put your script after the form, or use `$(document).ready()`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: Let me give that a try, and then I will read the article, regardless of whether it works. I will get back to you in just a second.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you so much for the help!! I'm going to read the article now. Thank you again, I really appreciate it!!